# Need help regarding showing star rating using jquery and css

Tags: jquery, css

Someone on Stackoverflow had suggested star rating and I accept it best suited for my coding. Initially it doesn't reflect but once I alert anything it does. Here is that coding...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    some_program();
    $(".stars").each(function() { 
        var val = $(this).data("rating");            
        var size = Math.max(0, (Math.min(5, val))) * 16;
        var $span = $('<span />').width(size);
        $(this).html($span);
    });
});
```

css

```
span.stars, span.stars span {display: block;background: url('../img/stars.png') 0 -16px repeat-x;width: 80px;height: 16px;}span.stars span {background-position: 0 0;}
```

Here is html coding:

```
<div id="response"></div>
//the span code below comes inside response id after ajax call "some_program();" under document ready
<span class="stars" data-rating="3"></span>
```

When I alert right after `some_program();`, it starts reflecting the star rating. I do not understand why it does not initially.

Comment: What does some_program() do? Ajax? Maybe move your star processing into the Ajax complete handler?

Comment: it brings the span code

Comment: Yes it worked! But for better understanding could you please tell why it doesn't if I code as given in my question?

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. That means the request is made but then execution continues with the next line of code *before* the Ajax response is received. The complete callback is called later, after the response. I would guess in your case the alert() allowed the Ajax response to be processed before you closed the alert.

Comment: Yes you are right, I did realize now. Thank you nnnnnn!